# Javascript / Jquery Image preview with canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, canvas

I am trying to preview my image with canvas after I select it in my input field, but I get an error,

This Html is generated, in this case 3 times:(ill just show one of those three)

```
<input type="file" class="ImageInput">
<img class="input-preview" src="http://placehold.it/654x363" style="width:280px;height:150px;display:none;" />
<canvas class="myCanvas" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
```

And this is my Js function which shall preview the image:

```
readURL: function() {

    var $input = $(this);

    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            $input.next('.input-preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
            var ctx = $input.next('.myCanvas').getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage($input.next('.input-preview')[0], 0, 0, 400, 200);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
    }

    $(".ImageInput").change(this.readURL);

},
```

But I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $input.next(...).getContext is not a function

At this line:

```
var ctx = $input.next('.myCanvas').getContext("2d");
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: `getContext` is a method of `CanvasElement`, not of `jQuery-object`.. Use `$input.next('.myCanvas').get(0)...`

Comment: And the canvas is not next element of file input

Comment: @Rayon thanks for your suggestion but it did not work I get the same error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try with following code:

```
var ctx = $input.nextAll('.myCanvas')[0].getContext("2d");
```

Your `.myCanvas` not next immediate sibling of file input. So to reach to canvas you need to use `.nextAll()` https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

Comment: Ok why the downvotes?  `$input.nextAll('.myCanvas').first()[0]` looks redundant but it is not false

Comment: This actually worked I get the preview but I do get the error aswell strange, I will try it out a couple times more

Comment: @A.Wolff - actually i never worked on canvas before so haven't thought of converting jQuery object to native DOM element. Later i updated my answer so that OP and other SO user will get correct information.

Comment: @JohnDoe2 - thanks for edit. You are correct. By `[0]` we are getting correct reference.

Answer (score 0):

Using `$input.next('.myCanvas')` will give you the jQuery object, which doesn't support `.getContext()`. You need to get the native JS version from the jQuery object (add `[0]` or `.get(0)` on the jQuery object):

```
var ctx = $input.nextAll('.myCanvas')[0].getContext("2d");
```

**Edit**: As commented by @A. Wolff using `$input.next('.myCanvas')` will not match anything as `.next()` will only look at the very next sibling (being the `img` in this case, which does not have a `myCanvas` class). So you would need to use [`.nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) instead.

Comment: THanks for your suggestion I tried it but it did not work, same error

Comment: @JohnDoe2 Because anyway `$input.next('.myCanvas')` doesn't match anything. It should be e.g: `var ctx = $input.nextAll('.myCanvas')[0].getContext("2d");`

Comment: @A.Wolff hmm what do you mean I do not get it

Comment: @JohnDoe2 See [DOC for `next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/), it targets only next following sibling which is not the case in your posted HTML markup: `Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.`

Comment: "*You need to get the native JS version from the jQuery object*" Did you meant the DOMElement ? jQuery is native javascript.